# How to calculate centrality in networking of NetLogo

Tags: networking, netlogo

I am new in using NetLogo , so I hope you can help me

I'm using network extension "nw". I calculated closeness, betweenness and eigne vector easily using this extension.

but I don't know how to code for katz- centrality,leverage_centrality  ,h_index centrality

Any help plz.

Answer (score 1):

NetLogo NW extension supports a limited set of algorithms, like all libs do.

Katz centrality might be similar enough eigenvector centrality algorithm. Please see https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension/blob/e5496b7d2a6819fdbed1b045000879e705ff9c48/src/main/org/nlogo/extensions/nw/algorithms/CentralityMeasurer.scala if you can modify it to match your needs.